Selection Box Not Positioning Correctly
I found some code that generates a selection box, but when I tried it the box was not starting where the mouse was and I couldn't find the issue.

using UnityEngine;

public class GUISelectionBox : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Draggable inspector reference to the Image GameObject's RectTransform.
    public RectTransform selectionBox;

    // Draggable inspector reference to the scene's rendering camera
    public Camera currentCamera;

    // This variable will store the world space position of wherever we first click before dragging.
    private Vector3 initialClickPosition = Vector3.zero;


    void Update()
    {
        // Click somewhere in the Game View.
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            // Get the initial click position of the mouse and transform it to world space, since screen space may change
            // z-coord is random and irrelevant, we just want a world space position
            initialClickPosition = currentCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 10f));


        }

        // While we are dragging.
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            // Store the current mouse position in screen space.
            Vector2 currentMousePosition = new(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);

            // transform initial position to current screen space
            Vector3 initBoxPosScreenSpace = currentCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(initialClickPosition);

            // calculate width and height of rect transform
            float width = currentMousePosition.x - initBoxPosScreenSpace.x;
            float height = currentMousePosition.y - initBoxPosScreenSpace.y;

            // set rect's pivot and size
            selectionBox.anchoredPosition = (Vector2)initBoxPosScreenSpace + new Vector2(width / 2, height / 2);
            selectionBox.sizeDelta = new Vector2(Mathf.Abs(width), Mathf.Abs(height));

        }

        // After we release the mouse button.
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
        {
            // Reset
            initialClickPosition = Vector3.zero;
            selectionBox.sizeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }
}

as for the inspector, I have the selection box as an image within a canvas everything was left default and I assigned the correct camera to it.

How are your camera, canvas, selection box, and selection box parent configured in the inspector?

I have the selection box as an image within a canvas everything was left default and I assigned the correct camera to it

I subtract half the screen because unity positions the rect in the middle but the code is for positioning it in the bottom corner
selectionBox.anchoredPosition = (Vector2)initBoxPosScreenSpace + new Vector2(width / 2, height / 2) - new Vector2(currentCamera.pixelWidth/2, currentCamera.pixelHeight/2);

